# Why is this booleans always a nil value in all conditions?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, lua, null

So I just starting to learn lua, and I was working on a small script for my game in Corona SDK, but the part of the script is pure lua .

Here's some code :

```
function checkNumAndExp(number)
local correct;
    if randomText == "bigger than " then
        if number > randomNumber then
            correct = true;
        end
      return correct;
    elseif randomText == "smaller than " then
        if number < randomNumber then
            correct = true;
        end
     return correct;
    elseif randomText == "multiples of " then
        if number%randomNumber == 0 then
            correct = true;
        end
      return correct;
    elseif randomText == "divisible by " then
        if number%randomNumber == 0 then
            correct = true;
            return correct;
        end
    else
      correct = false;
      return correct ;
    end

end
```

What I'am trying to do is to check if a given number is  bigger than  or  smaller than .... a random number generated at the beginning .

*Note : randomText is a random table item string that is equal to one of those values :*

> 1. Bigger than
> 2. Smaller than
> 3. Multiples of
> 4. divisible by

My current problem is that for all case correct always return a nil value . all other vars are not nil .

Any ideas what would be causing this ?

Comment: String comparison is sensitive to letter case and trailing space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Bigger than", "Bigger than ", "bigger than", and "bigger than " are all different strings.

---

More about your code:

> ```
> if number > randomNumber then
>     correct = true;
> end
> return correct;
> ```

The boolean expression `number > randomNumber` evaluates to `true` or `false`. If it evaluates to `true`, you then set a variable to `true`. You can streamline that by using the result of the expression directly:

```
correct = number > randomNumber
return correct
```

Given that you're immediately return the result, you don't even need the variable. You can just write:

```
return number > randomNumber
```

So your code could have been written:

```
function checkNumAndExp(number)
    if randomText == "bigger than " then
        return number > randomNumber
    elseif randomText == "smaller than " then
        return number < randomNumber
    elseif randomText == "multiples of " then
        return number%randomNumber == 0
    elseif randomText == "divisible by " then
        return number%randomNumber == 0
    end
    return false
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the reason was not in the strings, but rather in the structure of the if/else statements . now everything is working and it's much cleaner :) .